# Block a domain from signing up in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to block domains associated with fake user accounts (such as yopmail) from signing up to my Cognito user pool. I could write some client side code to check the email address of the signup, but thats not very reliable as it could be bypassed. If there a way I can do this server side with Cognito?

Answer (score 0):

In cognito there are triggers like [pre-sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) up. Use that feature to solve your problem.